# I want to combine these queries result

Tags: sql-server

I want to Combine this query please Help

```
select Semester,StudentID,CourseCode,AssignmentTitle,Score,CourseWeekName,MarksObtained
from (
           (
      select t.BatchID, t.TraineeID, t.VideoStartTime, t.VideoEndTime, t.VideoDuration,l.Week
      from dm.vTraineeActivity t
      inner join dm.vLessonDimension l 
      on t.LessonKey=l.LessonKey and t.BatchID=l.BatchID 
      where t.BatchID in (1,2)
    ) Vidoess

 (
      select sa.Semester, sa.StudentID, sa.CourseCode, sa.AssignmentTitle, sa.Score, sa.CourseWeekName
      from dstp_dm.lms.vStudentAssignment sa
      where semester in (1,2)
      and CourseWeekName <='Week 04'
    ) assign

full outer join
(
select Semester, StudentID, CourseCode, MarksObtained
from dstp_dm.lms.vStudentQuizResult 
where semester in (1,2)
    and CourseWeekName <='Week 04'
) quiz
```

Comment: Look at `UNION` on the MSDN documentation.

Comment: What queries do you want to combine? That *looks* like one query, but it's not valid. You have an unclosed set of parenthesis (`()`), and there's a syntax error after `Vidoess`; should there be a `JOIN`, there, or something? Sample data and expected results will greatly help us help you.

Comment: @SyntaxError you can't union across result sets with different field definitions